# Gorm returned value type

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an object Foo with a hasMany association to a Bar object

```
class Foo {
 String value
 static hasMany = [
  bars: Bar
 ]
}

class Bar {
 String value
}
```

when i try the follwing

```
def foo = Foo.find("from Foo f where f.value=:value",[value:value])
```

the type of the returned value foo is Foo, while when i do this

```
def foo = Foo.find("from Foo f left join f.bars b where b.value=:value",[value:value])
```

the type is an Object

Can anyone explain to me why ?

Thx, ken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second query selects properties of not just `Foo` but also `Bar`. If you `println foo`, the output for the second `foo` is something like this:

```
[Foo : 3, Bar : 2]
```

If you add `loggingSql = true` to your `dataSource` definition, Hibernate will output the actual SQL it's using to STDOUT - something like:

```
select
    foo0_.id as id0_0_,
    bar2_.id as id2_1_,
    foo0_.version as version0_0_,
    foo0_.value as value0_0_,
    bar2_.version as version2_1_,
    bar2_.value as value2_1_ 
from
    foo foo0_ 
left outer join
    foo_bar bars1_ 
        on foo0_.id=bars1_.foo_bars_id 
left outer join
    bar bar2_ 
        on bars1_.bar_id=bar2_.id 
where
    bar2_.value=?
```

OK. But how to avoid returning the `Bar` from the query? - I currently don't have a good solution.

I'd vote for using the [select clause with HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select), but in practice any of those syntaxes will produce an error in GORM. It may be possible to solve this by using a [Hibernate `Criteria`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.2%20Criteria), but I currently don't know how.

So, for a start, you might simply want to state:

```
def fooBar = Foo.find("from Foo f left join f.bars b where b.value=:value",
   [value:value])
def foo = fooBar[0]
assert foo instanceof Foo
```

EDIT: Note that for one-to-one associations the "dotty" syntax can be used, i.e.,

```
from Foo foo where foo.baz.value=:value
```